# I can't logout with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on my first laravel project in which I made an admin panel to make admin able to controller the website. I tried to login admin into dashboard and everything was fine, when I tried to log him out nothing works and the page was just reloading and redirect back.

Here is my logout button:

```
<a class="navbar-brand btn btn-primary btn-lg"
 href="{{route('admin.logout'))}}"> log out</a>
```

My route:

```
 Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout');
```

And my controller:

```
use Illuminate\support\Facades\Auth;


  public function logout(Request $request){
     
       Auth::logout();

        return redirect()->route('get.admin.login')
        ->with(['success'=>'logged out successfully']);
    }
```

I used `Auth::logout();` method from laravel official documentation, however it didn't work.
I hope I can find help.

Comment: What's your laravel version? This is happening fot auth constructor. Chaage your route name to logout to another like signout or another, it will solve the problem

Comment: My version is laravel 7

Comment: I changed the route name but still not working

Answer (score 0):

as your using `Auth::logout()`inside that function

```php
public function logout(Request $request) {
    Auth::logout(); 
    return redirect('/login');
}
```

here `Auth::` will be null
so apply `middleware` to get `Auth` instance and then you can logout

```php
Route::get('logout', 'LoginController@logout')->name('admin.logout')->middleware('auth');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following in your controller:

```
return redirect('login')->with(Auth::logout());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code, for logout the admin.

```
Auth::logout(); 
return redirect('/login');
```